# Joining Oracle Table Data with MongoDB Collection

Tags: oracle, mongodb

I have a reporting framework to build and generate reports (tabular format reports). As of now I used to write SQL query and it used to fetch data from Oracle. Now I have got an interesting challenge where half of data will come from Oracle and remaining data come from MongoDB based on output from Oracle data. Fetched tabular format data from Oracle will have one additional column which will contain key to fetch data from MongoDB. With this I will have two data set in tabular format one from Oracle data and one from MongoDB. Based on one common column I need to merge both table data and produce one data set to produce report.

I can write logic in java code to merge two tables (say data in 2D array format). But instead of doing this from my own, I am thinking to utilize some RDBMS in-memory data concept. For example, H2 database, where I can create two tables in memory on the fly and execute H2 queries to merge two tables. Or, I believe, there could be something in Oracle too like global temp table etc. Could someone please suggest the better approach to join oracle table data with MongoDB collection.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try and use Kafka and Spark Streaming to solve this problem. Assuming your data is transactional, you can create a Kafka broker and create a topic. Then make change to the existing services where you are saving to Oracle and MongoDB. Create 2 Kafka producers (one for Oracle and another for Mongo) to write the data as streams to the Kafka topic. Then create a consumer group to receive streams from Kafka. You may then aggregate the real time streams using a Spark cluster(You can look at Spark Streaming API for Kafka [1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html)) and save the results back to MongoDB (using Spark Connector from MongoDB [2](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/)) or any other distributed database. Then you can do data visualizations/reporting on those results stored in MongoDB.

Comment: Thank Vamsi for the reply. But considering the current use case, I don't think we need this solution since it will need infrastructure and more effort to implement. Also we are trying to have report only for configuration data so data will be less. I am looking for more options/tool which can provide me wrapper on top of oracle/mongoDB where i can have query and it fetches data from both places. In above answer, https://drill.apache.org/ look something similar. But I yet need to explore it. But again thanks so much for this solution you suggested. May be it will be for future.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion would be to use apache drill. https://drill.apache.org

You can use a mongo and JDBC drill bits and then you can join oracle tables and mongo collections together.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Let me explore this option and see if it fits in our solution.